# Calling to checkbox and button function

Tags: javascript, event-handling

Is it possible to call two function through one click in javascript.Separately function implementation coding is like this.

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="3" class="radio" value="3" onchange="checkbox(this.id)" name="c1"></input>
```

and second is

```
<button type="button" onclick="calculation()">Submit</button>
```

I want to call both function on single click.Are this possible??

1st function coding is like this

```
function checkbox(clicked_id)
{   

    var checkbox = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
    if(checkbox.checked==true)
    {
         // coordintaes for routes 


        //var m=65;
        // Get coordinates of route and display it
        for(m=1;m<=36;m++){

            //alert(m);
        $.ajax({
        url: "route_query4district.php?id="+m,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg1) 
        { 
        xarray1 = new Array();
         yarray1 = new Array();
         color1 = new Array();
        js_data1 = eval(msg1);
        //  alert(js_data1);
            var k1=0;
            for(j1=0;j1<js_data1.length;j1+=3){
            xarray1[k1] = js_data1[j1];
            yarray1[k1] = js_data1[j1+1];
            color1[m] = js_data1[j1+2];
            k1++;
            }
            alert(color1[1]);
            var flightPlanCoordinates = new Array();
            for(i=0;i<xarray1.length;i++){
             flightPlanCoordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(yarray1[i], xarray1[i]);
            }
            var contentString = '<div id="content">';
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: contentString
          });


            var mid_color=67+((parseInt(checkbox.value)));
            var last_color=36+((parseInt(checkbox.value)));
            var line_color=color1[m];

            var stroke_color=line_color.toString();
            var linee_color=color1;
            var strokee_color=linee_color.toString();
            flightPath[m] = new google.maps.Polygon({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                strokeColor: stroke_color,
                fillColor: line_color,
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 4
          });
          flightPath[m].setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,flightPath);
      });

         }
        });
        }

    }   // if checkbox is checked
```

and second function coding is

```
function calculation(){
           var laastyear= document.getElementById("LasttYear").value;
           var firstyeaar= document.getElementById("FfYear").value;
           var projecteedyear=  document.getElementById("ProjectedYear").value;
            // alert("hh");
            $.ajax({
            url: "test_dictrict_projections_folrmula.php?LastYear="+laastyear+"&FYEAR="+firstyeaar+"&ProjectYear="+projecteedyear,

          });

};

};
```

Comment: On which event you want to call those functions ?

Comment: actually i want  calculation function execute and than execute checkbox(clicked_id) through a submit button (type="button").

Comment: What if the onchange event is never occured ?

Comment: onchange event is required final output after calculation.

Comment: Still unable to figure out your requirment..If you want **checkbox()** function to be executed all the time then why you are attaching it onChnage event ?

Comment: actually i want to draw map on Google api along with some calculation.Each polygon will represent a  number.Thats why it is necessary 1st execute "calculation()" and than checkbox(clicked_id).I does not want to checkbox() function execute  all times.

Comment: I feel there is no need for onchange event, just check whether checkbox is checked on the submit event and make your calculations accordingly..

Comment: Are you want to say that checkbox will remain check and at every calculation polygon color will change dynamically?? if yes, than you can guide me how is this possible?? I am beginner in development field and have a little bit basic knowledge of java and js.

Comment: Thanks for nice idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the onclick is just a javascript part. You could place the whole function in there. Something like this should work:

```
onclick="calculation();checkbox(this.id);"
```

Comment: Thanks #Norbert
still not working. actually i want calculation function execute and than execute checkbox(clicked_id) through a submit button (type="button").

Comment: Then just add a onclick on the button :) http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Answer (score 0):

I dont wanna sound like a dumb.. but have you try adding two events listeners to the tag??.

Something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = 'es'>
    <head>
        <title> MY TEST </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type = 'button' value = 'Lets DO IT!' id = 'button'>
        <script>
            var inputButton = document.getElementById('button');
            inputButton.addEventListener('click', show1);
            inputButton.addEventListener('click', show2);

            function show1(){
                alert('Message 1');
            }

            function show2(){
                alert('Message 2');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```